# calculate external point of two CGPoint

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

What we have:
1)m_ptBulletStartPos point
2)touch move point

what to calculate :
External point on a line that pass throw bulletcover point and touch move point and rotate according to touch move.

How to get it: we create a method in which we draw dotted line , this function call according to another function that works according to touch move points response.

i have to calculate external point of two CGPoint.

My first CGPoint is -`ccp(m_ptBulletStartPos.x,m_ptBulletStartPos.y);`// fixed point

Second CGPoint is- At touchesMoved

i add the CGPoint object in one array.

```
                      External point(it will move accruing to touch moved
                         |
                         |
                         |
                         |
          ccp(m_ptBulletStartPos.x,m_ptBulletStartPos.y)// it should be fixed like anchor
                         |
                         |
                         |
                         |
                    Touch move point : ccp(touch.x,touch.y)
```

here is my code working according to [Finding external point](http://easycalculation.com/analytical/learn-ratio.php) but its not working correct.

```
CGPoint myexternalPoint=ccp(230,60);    //suppose
float fDistancem        = sqrt(pow(myexternalPoint.x - point.x, 2) + pow(myexternalPoint.y - point.y, 2));
float fDistancen        = sqrt(pow(myexternalPoint.x - m_ptBulletStartPos.x, 2) + pow(myexternalPoint.y - m_ptBulletStartPos.y, 2));    
CGFloat xdt=(fDistancem*point.x-fDistancen*m_ptBulletStartPos.x)/(fDistancem-fDistancen);
CGFloat ydt=(fDistancem*point.y-fDistancen*m_ptBulletStartPos.y)/(fDistancem-fDistancen);
CGPoint newexternalPoint = ccp(xdt, ydt);
NSLog(@"new externalPoint %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(newexternalPoint));
```

Comment: It's not obvious what are you trying to do. Are you sure the solution I gave in my answer doesn't work?

Comment: @Mr. Sulthan thanks for response,i don't have my macbook right now i will test it later! if its works surely i will accept your answer and up vote you for quick answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CGPoint fixedPoint = ...
CGPoint touchPoint = ...

CGPoint direction
direction.x = fixedPoint.x - touchPoint.x;
direction.y = fixedPoint.y - touchPoint.y;

CGPoint calculatedPoint;
calculatedPoint.x = fixedPoint.x + direction.x;
calculatedPoint.y = fixedPoint.y + direction.y;
```

Is this the point you want? If you want the point a bit further/nearer to the `fixedPoint`, just multiplicate `direction` with a factor.

For more info, you can google `vector algebra` or `analytic geometry`. Knowing the basics is a must for every programmer.